# Javascript Desctructuring setting objects property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have understood the spread operator which is

```
let color_lawn = {
title: "lawn",
color: "#00FF00",
rating: 0
```

};

```
const rateColor1 = (color, rating) => (
{...color, rating} );
```

which returns a new object with the passed object and its whole properties and value in the function parameter which is in my case color which below will be

```
console.log(rateColor1(color_lawn, 5));
```

Now my Question is this: if above call to the function calls with

```
console.log(rateColor1(color_lawn, 5))
```

What i don't understand is the 5 if we saying return the copy of the object `(
{...color, 5} );

Then how come rating changes to 5 when we did not use the rating: 5; or color.rating=5

Does this mean that rating is actually holding 2 things?  5 and pointing to the objects rating key.

Another example i understood perfectly is:

```
const rateColor = function(color, rating) {
return Object.assign({}, color, { rating: rating });
```

};

But i do not understand this `const rateColor1 = (color, rating) => ( {...color, rating} );` one how the 5 is assigned to the rating.

Comment: This is just how the ES6 syntax works. The function *does* mention `rating`, which serves *both* as property name and its value at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `{ rating }` is a shorthand for `{ rating: rating }`.

So, you are asking for all the properties of `color` plus a property `rating` set to variable `rating`'s value.

Comment: Now understood. thank you

Comment: If it helped you, please, rate the answer. Thanks.